# Big Query function to convert query results into JSON with column name as key and row values List

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I have a complex requirement to return big query results in JSON structure with key as column names and all values of column as a single list.
Below is an example.

| FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- |
| First1 | row1 |
| First2 | row2 |
| First3 | row3 |
| First4 | row4 |

The expected results like below

`{ "FirstName": ["First1","First2","First3","First4"], "LastName": ["row1","row2","row3","row4"] }`

Also column names should not be hardcoded in query. Because we have large number of columns and huge data in BQ.
I tried using functions TO_JSON_STRING, STRUCT but not meet criteria.
I am able to achieve using JAVA code and google libraries, but performance was impacted.
Appreciate help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below option

```
create temp function  extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function  extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
select format('{%s}', string_agg(r))
from (
  select format('"%s": %T', key,array_agg(val)) r
  from your_table t,
  unnest(extract_keys(to_json_string(t))) key with offset
  join unnest(extract_values(to_json_string(t))) val with offset
  using(offset)      
  group by key
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Query worked, but getting  error  "Output String too long while evaluating format", may be because of so many columns(more than 30)